# Solr fq wildcard

Tags: solr

```
$search = $solr->search($_GET['search'], 0, 100, array('fq' => 'sm_keywords:topnews', 'sort' => 'created desc'));
```

I am use a php library for Solr and have a field sm_keywords which has comma separated keywords.

Examples:

topnews,golf,tennis

beach,sports,volleyball

I want to do a query where I can match a keyword such as "sports" anywhere in the string. Currently it will only match at the beginning. I tried doing *keyword*, but I got a 400 error. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Can't you index every keyword as a separate value within the same multivalued field?

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I just added my comment as a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest you to do is to index every keyword as a separate term, probably even as a different value of the same multivalued field. That way your filter will work without the need of any wildcard.